# update a column in a sql table with a value from another table based on a relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a SQL query to update a column values with an Id from a different table

Example

```
Organization Table
Id Name
1  AA
2  BB

Events Table
Id Name OrgId
1  AA    NULL
2  AA    NULL
3  BB    NULL
```

Now, I would like to update OrgId of Events table with its respective Id from Organization table

I did try the below query but I had explicitly do it for each organization

```
UPDATE Event SET OrId=
  (SELECT DISTINCT O.ID FROM Organization O WHERE O.Name='AA') WHERE Name='AA'
```

**May I know a better way to do it automatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `join`:

```
update e
    set orid = o.id
    from event e join
         organization o
         on o.name = e.tenant;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a Merge using

```
MERGE Event AS e
USING Organization AS o
ON (e.Name= o.name) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET e.OrgId = o.id
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*;
```

The output clause is optional and will print out the Ids that are inserted into the Event table.

The Merge is quite powerful as it has other clauses that can be used for cases when data is only in one table and not the other. Here's a nice post which explains things clearly. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/